# Generating a single random integer in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to generate a unique random integer for the variable SEED. This code is part of a bigger script that is going to run multiple times and output each time, so feeding SEED with a non-duplicate random integer is important. Also, I tried `random.sample` and such that return lists/sequence not an integer, but this is not the case here because of the following line using torch.

```
SEED = random.randint(1, 1000)
random.seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
torch.manual_seed(SEED)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(SEED)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with the snippet you shared?

Comment: I need it to generate a duplicate free random integer, but it does not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is a little too brute-force, but randomly popping integers out of a list of integers seems to work:

```
min_seed = 1
max_seed = 1000
seed_list = [*range(min_seed, max_seed+1)]

n_repetitions = 300  # or whatever, as long as n_repetitions < len(seed_list)
for repetition in range(0, n_repetitions):
    seed = seed_list.pop(random.randint(min_seed,len(seed_list)))
```

Since the integers get popped out of the list as they're used as seeds, there won't be repeats.

Comment: Lengthy but functional but that's all that matters! Thanks!

Comment: Why the list comprehension instead of just `list(range(...))`?

Comment: No real reason, just cranking out code. :^)

I prefer the comprehension just because it conveys a bit more intention, at least to me - it reads as "I'm building a list" rather than "I want this other thing to be a list."

Comment: For what it's worth, `timeit` is telling me that `list(range(...))` is considerably faster. For 10,000 repetitions of each, the comprehension takes 0.198 sec, and `list(range(...))` 0.0855 sec. So there, a counterargument against my original way!

Comment: Update - `timeit` reveals a yet speedier way! `[range(...)]` clocks in at 0.00366 sec for 10,000 repetitions! I like that one... I'll edit it into the answer. Thanks for inspiring the hunt, @MarkRansom!

Comment: `[range(a, b)]` creates a list with length 1, but `list(range(a, b))` creates a list with length b - 1 - a.

Comment: @enzo that means the `pop` won't work on a list built that way.  Good catch.

Comment: @enzo - thanks! Forgot the unpacking. It's slower than the wrong version (rats), but still the fastest I've tried (0.0775 sec). Ought to be `[*range(...)]`. Ugh, typos... ;^)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `time.time()`:

```py
import time
SEED = int(time.time())
```

This is technically unique since it'll be a different timestamp every time you run the code.

Comment: even if I run it inside a loop that lasts around 3 hours?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is your use case, but why don't you initialize `SEED` outside the loop?

Comment: because if I do so it's going to run the loops with the same `SEED`. I need to run each iteration with a unique `SEED`.

Comment: What if I need to generate multiple unique seeds within 1 second? Your method will fail.

Answer (score 1):

As an ultimate solution cast UUID to long integer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530294/how-to-generate-unique-64-bits-integers-from-python#3530326):

```
import uuid
uuid.uuid4().int & (1<<64)-1
9518405196747027403L
```

Comment: how can I edit this to get up to 3 digits?

Comment: uuid.uuid4().int & (1<<10)-1

Comment: @MahanAghaZahedi while a UUID is guaranteed to be unique, a 3-digit piece of it is not.  In fact any manipulation will lose the uniqueness guarantee.