# Produce unique values on demand simply by incrementing an integer in python

Tags: python-3.x

Based on [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531557/4865723) I was wondering how to implement this.

The goal is to have unique numbers. They have to be unique in the process not outside of it.
So the recommendation was just to count.

```
import sys
i = iter(range(sys.maxsize))

# calling this will give you the next number
next(i)
```

What do you think about this approach?

Comment: why not uuid (mapped back to int)?

Comment: Btw, range is already a lazy iterator, you don't need to call `iter` on it. And what do you mean by outside of the process?

Comment: What is a lazy iterator? Any suggestions for alternatives? "outside" in the meaning of a uuid4 would be unique outside the process.

Comment: Lazy iterator means that you are not storing all the values simultaneously, but a state (one integer) and the iteration (increment by 1). I still not sure what you mean by unique outside the process. Do you mean reproducible? Giving the same values across different runs

Comment: No not reproducable. LAzy is good I think. I do not want to store all values from 0 to maxsize at once.